# download a pgp key automaticly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnupg, pgp

I want to download a pgp key from a keyserver automaticly using gpg like this:

```
    gpg --searchkey carol@example.com
```

gpg is giving me this result.

```
    gpg: searching for "carol@example.com" from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
    (1)     <carol@example.com>
              2048 bit RSA key 2F5E71CD, created: 2015-02-17
    Keys 1-1 of 1 for "carol@example.com".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit >
```

If I want to add this key to my keyring I need to press "1" and ENTER.

My **Question** is: Is there a way to insert automatically always the first found key from the keyserver to my keyring? Because if I want to do it with about 200 addresses it would be nice if I can import them by a script without sitting next to the computer and pressing always "1" and Enter.

I know that is a security risk to import automatically always the first key, but to import the keys automatically means not that I also trust them automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use mail addresses for finding keys when scripting. [Everybody can upload keys with arbitrary user IDs in them](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=president%40whitehouse.gov), **key servers to not check anything at all**. It is even easily possible to [calculate short key ID collisions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74009/what-is-an-openpgp-key-id-collision/74010#74010). Trusting arbitrary keys on key servers provides a very, very dangerous, false assumption of safety.

**For scripting purpose, always work with key fingerprints.** These are secure against collision attacks and provide a unique identifier for OpenPGP keys (in theory, they do not, but they provide a larger key address space than UUIDs do, which in practice are considered unique).

To download a list of fingerprints, use something like

```
gpg --recv-keys \
  0D69E11F12BDBA077B3726AB4E1F799AA4FF2279 \
  4AC1999F0BA293E8960AF2DA428C3085AF19CFE9 \
  ...
```

*(alternatively, remove the backslashes and put everything on a single line)*

To simply **fetch all keys** and **validate trust on another way** (eg. through the web of trust, but don't forget to do so), you have to script around GnuPG. Here is an [example script originally posted on security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42867/how-to-fetch-and-update-all-my-friends-keys), which takes a file containing one mail address per line and fetches all matching keys:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
    gpg --with-colons --batch --search $line 2>/dev/null | \
    awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" };  $1=="pub" { print $2 }' | \
    xargs gpg --recv-keys
done < $1
```

Comment: thx for your reply, but this doesn't answer my question. ok if i have a List of fingerprints than it is easy but I want to import if I don't know the fingerprint automatically and check the fingerprints later.

Comment: For doing so, you will have to script around GnuPG. I added some lines from an answer I posted as reply to another question on security.SE.