# Search .cvs file of email addresses for public pgp-keys

Tags: csv, terminal, gnupg

I have a list of mail addresses of friends (.csv) and I want to see if they have public keys stored on pgp keyservers. I want to get [this](https://individualit.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/collect-pgp-keys-of-all-your-contacts-from-keyserver/) going for Mac.

The pgp part is not the problem, however I can't get my head around the **for loop** to go through each element in the file...

```
for add in {cat contacts.csv | grep @}; do gpg --search-keys $add; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write loops just for running a single command for each line of a file, use `xargs` instead. [`cat` is also not required here.](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)

This small snippet is doing what you're trying to achieve:

```
grep @ contacts.csv | xargs -n 1 gpg --search-keys
```

If you insist in the loop, use the right parenthesis `$( ... )` runs the command in a subshell):

```
for add in $( grep @ contacts.csv ); do gpg --search-keys $add; done
```

I answered a similar, but not equal question on the [security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42870/19837) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566511/695343), you might also get some inspiration there.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! Need to find a proper introduction for working in the terminal I guess